# Auth0 password reset error

Tags: angular, auth0

I am using Angular 2 with lock version 10.8 and I am trying to add the ability for users to change their password. I've tried the following method, which calls the Management API, where the parameter `user_id` is the `user_id` received from the user's Auth0 profile, and the parameter `connection` is `'Username-Password-Authentication'`

```
public resetPassword(user_id: string, password: string, connection: string): Observable<any> {        
    let body = JSON.stringify({ password, connection });
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });        
    return this.authHttp.patch('https://https://manage.auth0.com/api/v2/users/' + user_id, body, options).map(response => {
        return response.json();
    }).catch(this.appService.handleError);
}
```

When using this code, I get the following error:

> OPTIONS
>   https://https//manage.auth0.com/api/v2/users/auth0%7C58b77f281667c9685d1019c3
>   net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

What am I doing wrong here?

Here are the two sources I was using: 
https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/password-change
https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/patch_users_by_id

And yes, the "Change Password flow v2" toggle is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `'https://https://manage.auth0.com/api/v2/users/'`

With `'https://manage.auth0.com/api/v2/users/'`

In your patch request.

The protocol is repeated twice in the url.

**Edit**

You also need to replace 'manage' with your Auth0 account name, `https://<account>.auth0.com/api/v2/users/`.

You can head over to https://manage.auth0.com/#/apis, click the `Auth0 Management API` link and in Settings the `identifier` field. This should be the base URL of your request.

Also make sure to check that `http://localhost:3000` is in the `Allowed Origins (CORS)` field in your client settings over at Auth0 dashboard.

Comment: I was wondering about that, but the documentation actually has "https" twice like I do. Weird. Maybe a typo on their part? Anyway, I made that change and now I am getting a 401 (Unauthorized) on the OPTIONS request method. It also says "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401."

Comment: Yes, that is likely a typo in the docs on their end. See my edited answer for the errors you are experiencing.

Comment: Had the wrong account at first. Got that fixed and now I'm getting a 403 (forbidden)

Comment: I think the problem here might be doing this from your SPA. It may require claiming additional [scopes](https://auth0.com/docs/scopes) such as update:users on the management api audience. This can bring some security issues in your app. Is there a specific reason why you don't want to use the [password reset email](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/password-change#using-the-authentication-api)? In that case I would look at moving the password reset logic to the server and using [client credentials](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/grant/client-credentials) to access the management API